# Golang with couchbase integration issue

Tags: go, couchbase

I'm using golang with couchbase integration component called go-couchbase. It's enable to connect with couchbase and retrieve data. However I have a problem to send start key and  skip value and limit value with this API. Because there is no functionality found by myself.

url : - `github.com/couchbaselabs/go-couchbase`

Please let me know any method to send these values to couchbase and retrieve data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That start key is only mentioned once, as a [parameter to a couhbase view](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/go-couchbase/blob/c750590224e2eabf3891d8e8b9f83cd800bea8ad/views.go#L167-L185):

```
// View executes a view.
//
// The ddoc parameter is just the bare name of your design doc without
// the "_design/" prefix.
//
// Parameters are string keys with values that correspond to couchbase
// view parameters. Primitive should work fairly naturally (booleans,
// ints, strings, etc...) and other values will attempt to be JSON
// marshaled (useful for array indexing on on view keys, for example).
//
// Example:
//
// res, err := couchbase.View("myddoc", "myview", map[string]interface{}{
// "group_level": 2,
// "start_key": []interface{}{"thing"},
// "end_key": []interface{}{"thing", map[string]string{}},
// "stale": false,
// })
func (b *Bucket) View(ddoc, name string, params map[string]interface{}) (ViewResult, error) {
```

I suppose the `skip` one (mentioned in "[Pagination with Couchbase](http://blog.couchbase.com/pagination-couchbase)") is just another parameter to add to the `params map[string]interface{}`.